# In what cases do browsers create multiple adjacent text nodes?

Tags: html, ios, web, safari, mobile-safari

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text),

> New documents have a single Text node for each block of text. Over time, more Text nodes may be created as the document's content changes

I'm running into a rare bug in a project that I think is triggered by multiple text nodes being created in a single element when I only expect there to be one, but I can't reproduce it. Is there any way I can trigger this browser behavior, particularly in iOS Safari?

To illustrate, I manually made a div with two text nodes. I'm trying to figure out when the browser would take a single text node and split it in two like in the attached image[image]

Comment: _but I can't reproduce it._ how we can't test it ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I'm not asking to reproduce my bug, I'm asking how to trigger this documented browser behavior.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245503/multiple-text-nodes-in-a-single-element) can help you

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Thanks. My situation is different from that question. I want to know how to actually make that happen, and I'm not using contenteditable.

Answer (score 1):

At least one case of particularly Safari/WebKit unexpectedly breaking textNodes seems to be documented somehow in WebCore’s [HTMLConstructionSite.cpp](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/68ae0fde5f959e056fbd6700f1ca7fa652cd1ffa/Source/WebCore/html/parser/HTMLConstructionSite.cpp#L584-L592) lines 584–592, which refers to [WebKit bug #55898](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55898). The limit comes from [Text.h](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/68ae0fde5f959e056fbd6700f1ca7fa652cd1ffa/Source/WebCore/dom/Text.h) which sets `defaultLengthLimit` to `1 << 16` (65536).

I’m not entirely sure which part triggers this, since adding long text to node using `textContent` or `appendChild(textNode)` both created a single text node even with long text. However, I did manage to replicate this behavior with `innerHTML`.

Example:

```js
// empty <p> element
let p = document.getElementById("test");
p.innerHTML = "a".repeat(65536+100);
console.log(p.childNodes.length); // 2
```

Obviously HTMLConstructionSite.cpp is related to parsing HTML so it would make sense that it applies to `innerHTML`, but I have no idea if some other places in WebCore use the text splitting textNode creation too. I hope this helps to track down the problem at least.

Comment: This is really helpful and I think points me in the right direction. Thanks a lot!